# How to return the same variable across multiple functions

Tags: javascript

How can I return `__plugin` inside `add` and `css` function without `return __plugin` inside them. Can I use a higher order function? Everything is working as expected but I would like to know and maybe refactor this code.

**I don't want to write `return __plugin` every time only one time**.

```
const $ = (el) => {
  let _plugin = {};
  const element = document.querySelector.bind(document);
  const css = (style) => {
    Object.assign(element(el).style, style)
    return _plugin;
  }
  const add = (c) => {
    element(el).classList.add(c)
    return _plugin;
  }
  _plugin = { add, css }
  return  _plugin
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to return `__plugin` and you don't want to return `__plugin`?

Comment: yeah... what you wrote is just weird. Still, what about using a callback function? the callback could get __plugin as a parameter... Javascript people love them callbacks

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes I don't want to write `return __plugin` every time . I just want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Why do you need to return an empty object within the first two expressions anwyway?  You're not actually modifying it until after the expressions.

Comment: If you want a function to return a value other than *undefined*, you must have a return statement that returns some other value. So there's no other way to go about it.

Comment: @Derek—the `$` function returns an object with *add* and *css* methods. The OP wants to be able to chain function calls, e.g. `$('#foo').add(className).css({backgroundColor: 'red'});`

Comment: I don't understand the repeated calls to *element*, it could resolve to a different DOM element for subsequent calls. Surely it would be better to resolve it once when first called and keep a closure the actual element?

Comment: @RobG Yes, nice observation. I can use something like this: `let element = document.querySelector.bind(document);
  element = element(el);` Thanks for the support Rob.

Comment: @RobG I've made an answer which uses a higher-order function to make all of the functions chainable. Perhaps you'd be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a higher-order function which wraps around each of the functions in your `_plugin` object, and it will make all of your functions chainable.

```js
const chainable = (obj) => {
  for (const key in obj) {
    const func = obj[key];
    if (typeof func === 'function') {
      obj[key] = function () {
        const val = func.apply(this, arguments);
        return val === undefined ? this : val;
      };
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

const $ = (el) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(el);
  const css = (style) => {
    Object.assign(element.style, style);
  };
  const add = (c) => {
    element.classList.add(c);
  };
  return chainable({ add, css });
};

/* Testing code */

$('#test')
  .add('testClass')
  .css({ 'background-color': 'black' });
```

```css
.testClass { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="test">Testing</div>
```

Comment: Thank. Is there a similar function in lodash or ramda?

Comment: @jonathandion I don't know of one, but you could certainly use those libraries to simplify the code for `chainable`. `_.functionsIn(obj).forEach` could replace the `for in` loop and `if` statement.

Comment: Amazing stuff I refactored your code: https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/f1uc7v9p/7/ What do you think?

Comment: @jonathandion That looks good. For reliability's sake, I didn't use `func.name` because it's not necessarily the same as the key in the object (see the documentation for [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)).

Comment: Yes, exactly I was reading the code again and same thought. I updated the code. I would like to D.M you for further questions. Thanks.

Comment: @jonathandion You can message me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5743988/4castle) anytime, and I'll get notified.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to attach objects to those variables with something like this:

```
const $ = (el) => {
    const element = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    const css = (style) => {
        Object.assign(element(el).style, style);
    };
    const add = (c) => {
        element(el).classList.add(c);
    };

    return {add, css};
};
```

Otherwise you'd just be returning undefined objects since plugin is never manipulated (or dependent on multiple conditions rather).

Comment: The idea is to chain calls, so each function has to return the *_plugin* object. It's not *undefined*, it has *add* and *css* methods which have a closure to *element*.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.. you could do a minor refactor like so:

```
const $ = (el) => {
   const element = document.querySelector.bind(document);

   const css = function(style) {
    Object.assign(element(el).style, style)
    return this;
   }

   const add = function(c) {
    element(el).classList.add(c)
    return this;
   }

   return  { add, css };
};
```

If you want to get rid of using plugin and keep the ability to chain, swap out the inner arrow function for regular functions. This allows you to return this which is scoped to $.

Comment: *this* is never bound to "*where ever [a function] was called from*". It's set by the call, *bind* or lexically for arrow functions.